# Postgres Initialize script not working Docker version 3.4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to dockerize an application and in my application, i have the following

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development

  database:
    image: postgres:10.12
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  db_data:
```

In my init.sql file

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER USER user1 WITH SUPERUSER;
```

i have already run `chmod +x init.sql`

In my .env file i have the following

```
DATABASE_NAME=tools_development
DATABASE_USER=user1
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_HOST=database
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.0

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.1.4

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing


RUN apt-get install -y bash git build-essential nodejs libxml2-dev openssh-server libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev postgresql-client libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libpq-dev tzdata

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle check || bundle install 

COPY . ./ 

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

But each time I run `docker-compose run --build` and try to run my application. I get error:

`could not translate host name "database" to address: Name or service not known`

I have tried everything possible but still the same error.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?

I know the issue is happening because the postgres initialize scripts are not running. I have seen a lot of options online and i have tried everything but I am still facing the same error.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [postgres docker image documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md) you can see that the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` are the necessary environment variables to setup the postgres container

You could add these environment variables to your `.env` file.  So the file will be as follow:

#### .env

```
DATABASE_NAME=tools_development
DATABASE_USER=user1
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_HOST=database

POSTGRES_USER=user1
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=tools_development
```

These environment variables will be used from the postgres container to init the DB and assign the user, so you can get rid of the `init.sql` file

After that you need to add the reference of the `.env` file in the database(postgres:10.12) service.
So your docker compose file should be as follow:

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
...
  database:
    image: postgres:10.12
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env 
...
```

Comment: this doesnt fix the problem @Gerassimos but thanks for the help